# macOS Settings will not let me change region from Afghanistan

Tags: macos, settings, geolocation

I reinstalled macOS. I must have mistakenly chosen Afghanistan as my region. However, now I cannot change it.

In **Settings** > **General** > **Language & Region**, there is a drop-down list to select a new region. I chose **Americas** > **United States**, and the Settings app flickers for a moment, and puts back the "Afghanistan" value.

My laptop has been in the United States this whole time. macOS is at the latest security patch version: `13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d)`.

My iCloud ID is logged in from the laptop. Oddly, though, it shows a parrot icon, but my other devices show a sunflower icon. On the laptop, in **Settings** > **Apple ID**, I can see my other devices. On my iPhone, in **Settings** > **Apple ID**, I can see the laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the AppleLocale via terminal.app...

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale -string "en_US"`

if you still have trouble, you can also try deleting the folder:  `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` and rebooting, then running `defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale -string "en_US"`again.

The Settings > General > Language & Region now responds should you wish to change the Region again.

Comment: This fixed it. My entire process: `defaults write`; Settings app showed Afghanistan; `sudo defaults write`; Settings app showed Afghanistan; restart macOS; Settings app showed US.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reinstall MacOS.

First boot into Recovery Mode. On Intel Macs, hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while booting. On Apple Silicon Macs, power off and then hold down on the power button. You will see **Continue holding for startup options**. When you see "Loading startup options" let go of the button.

Now select **Reinstall MacOS**. This will not (I repeat NOT) delete any of your data. In the setup process, make sure to select **United States** as your region.

Comment: This is, so far as I know, the only way to change Region. I was about to put this answer in, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry for dv but as accepted answer shows, incorrect.